# Crystal Report with data set shows report empty

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Hi I am using Crystal Report with dataset but when i run the report it shows Blank records hear is my code

```
    private void UpdateReport()
    {
        try
        {
            DateTime StDate = dtpFrom.Value;
            DateTime EdDate = dtpTo.Value;
            DataSet reportData = new DataSet();
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DBConnect.CaptureManagerConnectionSting);
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_GetBountyModelGrouping", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Region", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = cboRegion.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Country", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = cboCountry.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@StDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = StDate.ToShortDateString();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@EdDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = EdDate.ToShortDateString();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(reportData, "DataTableBountyModelGrouping");
            conn.Close();
            crptBountyModelGrouping rptDoc = new crptBountyModelGrouping();
            rptDoc.SetDataSource(reportData.Tables[0]);
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Please help me on this 
Thanks
V.G .Salger